# CSS help, how to target this link inside of div

Tags: css, hyperlink, colors, tags

I want to change "Read BIC Magazine Digital Edition" link red (look at attached picture).

[screen shot of link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0RCy.png)

I only have access to the css, this is what it looks like.

```
.logo .header_links{
margin-top:30px;
position:absolute;
right:0px;
bottom:33px;}

.header_links a{
 display:inline-block;
 font-family: 'verdana', 'arial', sans-serif;
 color: #0060AF;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration:underline;
padding:0 10px;
border-left: 1px solid #666;
 margin:0px -4px 0px 0px;}

.header_links a;"Read BIC Magazine Digital Edition"{
color: red;}

.header_links a:first-child{
  border-left:0px;}

.header_links a:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
```

Also this is what the link looks like:

```
<a href="http://www.bicmagazine.com/info/read-bic-magazine-online">Read BIC Magazine Digital Edition</a>
```

If I change the color of .header_links a all the links change color. how do I specify change the color of the Read BIC Magazine Digital Edition link. If you could put the code in a copy and paste format that would be awesome! thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you share the HTML around the link?  We need more context to help

Comment: The website is bicmagazine.com, I could copy and paste the HTML if that would help.

Comment: Yes, please add the HTML to the question itself.  For the HTML, yuo don't need to give us the entire site, just the relevant bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the link is the first link in the header, and if you only have access to CSS, you can do as follows:

```
.header_links a:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

Or, you can target the link by its `href` attribute:

```
.header_links a[href="http://www.bicmagazine.com/info/read-bic-magazine-online"] {
    color: red;
}
```

If none of this work, try setting the color as `!important`:

```
color: red !important;
```

In order to override the previous selector.

Comment: No problem. glad to help :)